# Counting results that have two different values in the same column

Tags: mysql, sql

I work in support and I am trying to count how many 'cases' have both of these labels applied:

'Chat' and 'Escalated'

This is the query I am using, but I am getting an incorrect number:

```
    select count(pk_case_number)
    from cases c
    join labels l
    on l.case_number = c.case_number
    where lower(label_name) = 'chat' 
    and exists (select distinct case_number
    from cases c
    join labels l
    on on l.case_number = c.case_number
    where l.case_number = c.case_number
    and lower(label_name) = 'escalated')
    and date(created_at) > '2013-08-11'
```

'created_at' is in the cases table.

Answer (score 1):

The following query lists all the cases where the condition is true:

```
select pk_case_number
from cases c join
     labels l
     on l.case_number = c.case_number
group by pk_case_number
having sum(lower(label_name) = 'chat') > 0 and
       sum(lower(label_name) = 'escalated') > 0;
```

The following counts them:

```
select count(*)
from (select pk_case_number
      from cases c join
           labels l
           on l.case_number = c.case_number
      group by pk_case_number
      having sum(lower(label_name) = 'chat') > 0 and
             sum(lower(label_name) = 'escalated') > 0
     ) t
```

I like doing these sorts of queries with aggregation and the `having` clause, because I find that to be the most general.  It is easy to add new labels that are required or to exclude a particular label (use `= 0` rather than `> 0`).

Comment: `having sum(lower(label_name) = 'chat') > 0 and            sum(lower(label_name) = 'escalated') > 0` I dont get it... when SUM("chat") number is 0, then could be MILIONS of "escalated" and count still going to be 0 (AND in HAVING shouldn't be OR).

Comment: The first query lists all of the cases, but I got a syntax error for the second one. In any case, I figured out how to count the cases that have both labels:

    select count (case_number)
from cases c 
join labels l
on l.case_numnber = c.case_number
where l.label_name = 'Chat'
AND EXISTS (select case_number
from cases c2 
join labels l2
on l2.fk_case_number = c2.case_number
where l2.label_name = 'Escalated'
and l.fk_case_number = l2.fk_case_number)

Comment: @user2770466 . . . I find it hard to see where the syntax error might be on the second query.  It should be `select count(*) from (<first query>) t`.